# SQL Statment Includes ${$variable}, Not Sure What It Does

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm updating an old web application to PHP 7.4 and PDO. I found something in an SQL statement that I've not seen before and I can't find anything on the web (maybe just not sure how to ask the question).  Database is MySQL.

`UPDATE location_info SET storeid = ${$locationid} WHERE...`

Can someone explain the use of the `${}` around the PHP variable?

Comment: Unless they were being [clever](https://3v4l.org/QfmSm), this is probably a typo that no one has noticed so far. I know I’ve done it when copy and pasting.

Comment: `${myVariable}` is a replacement token in Javascript. It will only work if the string is terminated with backquotes.

Comment: Impossible to say without actually seeing the surrounding source code, but if this is inside a double quoted string, it would be a [variable variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), equivalent to typing `$$locationid` without the braces, which aren't needed here. They're usually used when you have a double quoted string that contains a variable with no whitespace around it. For example, if you had a variable `$FOO` and you wanted the contents of the variable followed by the string `BAR` then you'd have to do `"${FOO}BAR"` because `$FOOBAR` is a different var.

Comment: The comment by @AlexHowansky is the best explanation.  Looking back at previous code, ```$locationid = "store-" . $z;``` makes me think the variable-variable is what the original dev was doing.  I'm not sure if the curly braces were added for readability or if he thought they were needed. (Or because of requirements by early versions of PHP and MySQL).  But, as it turns out, this was not some obscure SQL syntax to achieve a special result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**String interpolation**

You can read it at :

https://riptutorial.com/php/example/22788/string-interpolation

https://phppot.com/php/variable-interpolation-in-php/

But that syntax has been deprecated in PHP 8.2, and will removed in PHP 9.0 :

https://php.watch/versions/8.2/$%7Bvar%7D-string-interpolation-deprecated

Comment: Along with the @AlexHowansky comment above, this answered my question - especially the third link.